# Meaning of the phrase "a reckoning for..."

Tags: phrase-meaning

The headline of an article in "The Week" about Biden's plan on taxes increase is: "Democratic tax plan is a reckoning for the left".

1. On the face of the article it may seem that the plan will make the left to stump up (to this approach speaks a line in the article: "Yet it also doesn't appear to "fundamentally change" the lives of America's superrich").
2. But then it goes about: "Although the plan would increase the top personal income tax rate to 39.6 percent from the current 37 percent and add a 3 percent surtax to incomes over $5 million" and then: "And one wealth planner tweeted that the changes were "FANTASTIC for the uber-wealthy." This gets me to think of the plan making up to the left (playing in their favour).

What does the phrase "...a reckoning for the left" mean, after all?

Comment: a time to face up to some reality or other or to come to terms with something.

Comment: @Lambie I doubt if I have understood you rightly. The backwash of the plan would be negative for the left, wouldn't it?

Comment: You mean: backlash against the plan. Not backwash.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. How would you relay the headline with your own words?